# updating lines previously written to power shell ISE console

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to update lines that have been already written to the console. Let's say I have a function to download X number of files. If a function invocation downloads 5 files, I first want to print them, one on each line:

```
WIll donwload this files:
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
```

As soon as each file gets downloaded I want to add a check mark symbol next to the file name. So somehow I need the Write-Host (or some other write) know that it should move 5 lines above and 6 spaces to the right after the first file is downloaded.

Now sure if this is possible. I could move the cursor in the PS console using

```
Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates $x , $y
```

but not in ISE. It ignores the settings in ISE.

Comment: You could `clear` and redraw. Or you could use `Write-Progress` when a file is downloading, and `Write-Host` when it is complete.

Comment: Either stream your output (as Jacob Colvin notes) or don't use the ISE. The ISE isn't a console app.

Comment: Thanks. 'clear' would clear all previous commands from the screen. I think write-progress may be a good option and it does not write to the console; a window pops up with a progress bar which is nice.

Comment: I'm saying you would need to `clear` and then have a function that re-draws *everything* along with your changes. So you would have `Function DrawScreen {}` that accepted the array of items you were downloading as well as a completion status for each item (you can use a hashtable to combine these), and would print the updated results every time they needed to be changed.